# How can I apply multiple "filters" in one ImageProcessor.Web request?

Tags: c#, imageprocessor

I'm using the ImageProcessor.Web library in a .NET application. It is all working and seems great, but I'm wondering if there is a way to apply multiple filters (https://imageprocessor.org/imageprocessor-web/imageprocessingmodule/filter/) in the one request?

I'm specifically wanting to convert images to B&W, then invert them upon request:
e.g. /myimage.jpg?filter=blackwhite&filter=invert

Comment: Do you have reason to believe that using one request would improve things? Image processing is at least a bit of work, so the increased latency of multiple requests might not be as significant.

Comment: Why the ImageSharp tag? That's an entirely different library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The System.Drawing `ColorMatrix` class does not provide methods to multiply matrices to combine values which is how filters would normally be combined.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imaging.colormatrix?view=netframework-4.8

Because of this I never designed the filter rules to allow for multiple combined requests.

However, there is nothing to stop you implementing and registering your own [`IWebGraphicsProcessor`](https://github.com/JimBobSquarePants/ImageProcessor/blob/a94fb903e49f6fa5f47c6ea58d27af55ce8ff89c/src/ImageProcessor.Web/Processors/IWebGraphicsProcessor.cs#L19) that allowed combining the commands into a single command.